# Can i plug SFP Transceiver into SFP+ port?

Tags: dell, switch, port, fiber

I`m talking about [DELL PowerConnect 6248](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?c=us&cs=555&l=en&oc=MLB1851&s=biz) here.

For Module 1 bay you can buy *PowerConnect 6xxx SFP+ Module supports up to two SFPs (no SFPs included)*

Can i plug into these those Transceivers that are offered for front end SFP ports :

> [**SFP** Optical Transceiver, 1000BASE-LX, LC](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/networking_enterprise_class/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=320-2879)

instead of what DELL offers for Modular Upgrade Bay 1: Optics: ??

> [POWERCONNECT 6XXX Long Range, Single-Mode **SFP+** Optic](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=330-2404)

?

That is 1Gbit instead of 10Gbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules should be compatible (at the lower speed); but you should confirm this with Dell first. Newer switches typically require a SFP rev B or C (or 2/3 depending on what moniker the manufacturer is using). The 10Gb SFP+ sockets are usually backward compatible with SFP Rev.C, but because the SFP+ socket works differently this is *not guaranteed*.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, SFP will work in SFP+ slot, but SFP+ optics do not work in SFP slots. But in fact, for this question, it may depend greatly on the switch models – sometimes SFPs are supported in SFP+ ports, and sometimes not. For example, almost all SFP+ ports of Cisco switch can support SFPs and many SFP+ ports of Brocade switch only support SFP+. Though it’s feasible often, it’s safer to ask your switch vendor for some information.